# Laravel S3 file checking breaks

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have a pretty straight forward setup. I'm trying to check and see if a file exists in my bucket. But every time I get `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached` I'm not trying/going to increase my nesting.

```
$image = '/images/ch-' . $id;

if(!\Storage::disk('s3')->exists($image)) 
{
    return $image;
}
```

I check the documentation and I'm not seeing anything wrong that I'm doing. Maybe someone else has had a similar issue?

Comment: Can't replicate it, show the rest of the function please.

Comment: If you aren't going to increase the nesting level, then why don't you just disable xdebug?

Answer (score 0):

Can't assume the cause unless you show more code. But you can do this in order to prevent it.

In `bootstrap/autoload.php` add this line before `define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));`

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);
```